# What is best practise to Store a list of Objects in a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, list, hibernate, kotlin, jsonb

I want to create a table named "post" which has multiple tags, but max 6 tags per post.

When I create an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
data class Post(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,
    var title: String,
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var tags: List<Tag> = emptyList(),
    )
```

Then in my PostgreSQL database I have 3 tables:

1. post
2. post_tags
3. tag

Is this the way to go to have good performance or is there a better way?

For example, instead of having a list of tags, does it make sense using JSONB which can include a map of tagIds, so that I only have two tables (post, and tag) instead of three tables?

Or are there any other approaches?

So it makes sense to do it like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
data class Post(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,
    var title: String,
    @ManytToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tag",
    joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "post_id")],
    inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")],)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("posts")
    var tags: Set<Tag> = mutableSetOf()
    )
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "Tag")
@Table(name = "tag")
data class Tag(
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
val id: Long? = null,
val name: String,
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("tags")
var posts: Set<Post> = mutableSetOf(),

)
```

Do I need the referencedColumnName = "id" inside the JoinColumn() nest to name = "..."?

Answer (score 0):

You need that join table if a post can have many tags, and a tag can be attached to many posts.  It's a many-to-many relationship.

It sounds like you're wavering between a relational schema and a JSON document representation.  You give something up when you abandon a relational approach.  Consider carefully.